# Bash & Sql - Remove specialChar from multiple filename

Tags: php, sql, bash, filenames

I'm pretty new to terminal, and I'm facing this kind of situation. I have a lot of file, wich filename are stored in a DB.

Due to some import errors my situation is to have filename like this:

```
5970-CentroCivicodelquartiereLibertÃ .jpg
```

where the last char (à) has been replaced with: [Ã ]

Is there any way to simply remove all this "special char" from filenames both in folder and in SQL.

Either some idea for do this in php could work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tr` to get rid of the *special char*, i.e. `Ã`:

```
tr -cd "[:print:]"
```

For example:

```
$ foo="5970-CentroCivicodelquartiereLibertÃ .jpg"
$ tr -cd "[:print:]" <<< "${foo}"
5970-CentroCivicodelquartiereLibert .jpg
```

In order to do that for all files in a directory, you could say:

```
for i in * ; do new="$(tr -cd "[:print:]" <<< "$i")"; mv "$i" "$new"; done
```

EDIT: In order to remove the spaces as well, say:

```
for i in * ; do new="$(tr -cd "[:print:]" <<< "$i" | tr -d " ")"; mv "$i" "$new"; done
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, and for the space char?

Comment: @Teo_ne Pipe the result to `tr -d " "`

Comment: Ok cool, thanks a lot. So I have to run the command twice, one for special char and one for spaces right? Can't I join them?

Answer (score 0):

At the end I solved with this bash command:

```
find . -depth -exec rename -n 's/[^[:ascii:]]/_/g' {} \; | cat -v
find . -depth -exec rename -n 's/[^A-Za-z0-9\.\/_-]//g' {} \; | cat -v
```

-n means that have no-act, remove it after some test.

Then i cicle trought the file in the folder and update the value in DB. This has been possible as filename where formatted like ID-filename.ext (ex: 1245-Duomo.jpg where 1245 was the corrispective id in the DB).